# Accessing a route directly redirects to login page

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

I have the following route in Routes.php of my codeigniter4 application

`$routes->get('/ticket/access_token/(:any)', 'Ticket::access_token/$1');` 
I have the function access_token doing a certain action in the Ticket controller

I find that when i access the url `http://localhost/<projectname>/public/index.php/ticket/access_token/123` I get redirected to my login page instead of going to the access_token method in Ticket controller.

My **Filters.php** has the following content:

```
public $aliases = [
        'csrf'          => CSRF::class,
        'csrfToken' => CsrfToken::class,
        'toolbar'       => DebugToolbar::class,
        'honeypot'      => Honeypot::class,
        'invalidchars'  => InvalidChars::class,
        'secureheaders' => SecureHeaders::class,
        'auth'     => \App\Filters\Auth::class,
        'isLoggedIn' => \App\Filters\Authentication::class,
        'isGranted' => \App\Filters\Authorization::class,
        'checkpassreset'=> \App\Filters\CheckPassReset::class
    ];



 public $globals = [
'before' => [
 //'honeypot',
'csrf' => ['except' => ['Admin/index','Dashboard/index']],
'isLoggedIn' => ['except' => ['/', 'ticket/access_token', 'logout','auth','auth/forgotpassword','Admin/index','Dashboard/index']],
'isGranted' => ['except' => ['/', 'ticket/access_token', 'logout','auth', 'blocked', 'home','auth/forgotpassword','Admin/index','Dashboard/index']],
'checkpassreset' => ['except' => ['/',  'ticket/access_token', 'logout','auth','auth/forgotpassword']],
],
'after' => [
//'toolbar',
 'csrfToken',
// 'honeypot',
],
];
```

Content of **Filters/auth.php**

```
<?php namespace App\Filters;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\RequestInterface;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\ResponseInterface;
use CodeIgniter\Filters\FilterInterface;
class Auth implements FilterInterface
{
public function before(RequestInterface $request, $arguments = null)
{
// if user not logged in
if(! session()->get('email')){
// then redirct to login page
session()->destroy();
 return redirect()->to('auth');

}
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------
public function after(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, $arguments = null)
{
// Do something here
}
}
```

Does the auth filter call automatically even if i did not specify it explicitly in the route? Then how will i prevent auth from calling automatically and do it only for routes like `$routes->get('/dashboard','Dashboard::index',['filter' => 'auth']);`

My **Routes.php** :

```
<?php

namespace Config;

// Create a new instance of our RouteCollection class.
$routes = Services::routes();

// Load the system's routing file first, so that the app and ENVIRONMENT
// can override as needed.
if (is_file(SYSTEMPATH . 'Config/Routes.php')) {
    require SYSTEMPATH . 'Config/Routes.php';
}

/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Router Setup
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
$routes->setDefaultNamespace('App\Controllers');
$routes->setDefaultController('Home');
$routes->setDefaultMethod('index');
$routes->setTranslateURIDashes(false);
$routes->set404Override();
// The Auto Routing (Legacy) is very dangerous. It is easy to create vulnerable apps
// where controller filters or CSRF protection are bypassed.
// If you don't want to define all routes, please use the Auto Routing (Improved).
// Set `$autoRoutesImproved` to true in `app/Config/Feature.php` and set the following to true.
$routes->setAutoRoute(false);

/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Route Definitions
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 */

// We get a performance increase by specifying the default
// route since we don't have to scan directories.
$routes->get('/', 'Home::index');

$routes->get('/users', 'Users::index',['filter' => 'auth']);

$routes->get('/auth', 'Auth::index');
$routes->get('/ticket/access_token/(:any)', 'Ticket::access_token/$1');

$routes->post('/auth', 'Auth::index');
$routes->post('/api', 'API::index');
$routes->post('/dashboard','Dashboard::index',['filter' => 'auth']);
$routes->get('/dashboard','Dashboard::index',['filter' => 'auth']);

$routes->get('auth/logout','Auth::logout');
$routes->get('logout','Auth::logout');

$routes->get('auth/forgotpassword','Auth::forgotpassword');
$routes->post('auth/forgotpassword','Auth::forgotpassword');


$routes->post('/admin','Admin::index',['filter' => 'auth']);
$routes->get('/admin','Admin::index',['filter' => 'auth']);



/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Additional Routing
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * There will often be times that you need additional routing and you
 * need it to be able to override any defaults in this file. Environment
 * based routes is one such time. require() additional route files here
 * to make that happen.
 *
 * You will have access to the $routes object within that file without
 * needing to reload it.
 */
if (is_file(APPPATH . 'Config/' . ENVIRONMENT . '/Routes.php')) {
    require APPPATH . 'Config/' . ENVIRONMENT . '/Routes.php';
}
```

Comment: share code of your routes.php

Comment: I modified the route for access_token in Filters.php as /ticket/access_token/* and it worked